# Can't use JPCAP in Android project

Tags: java, android, packet-capture, jpcap

I want to create an application which can capture packets traffic with my Android device. I use Jpcap library but the LogCat prints the following error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jpcap.JpcapCaptor

My code is:

```
import jpcap.JpcapCaptor;
import jpcap.NetworkInterface; 
import jpcap.NetworkInterfaceAddress; 
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    private TextView net_devise;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) 
    {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );       
    }

    public void informations( View v )
    {
        NetworkInterface[] device = JpcapCaptor.getDeviceList(); 
        net_devise = ( TextView )findViewById( R.id.textview );

        int i = 0; 
        for ( NetworkInterface d : device ) 
        { 
            net_devise.setText( i++ + "\n" + "Description: " + d.description + "\n" + "d.datalink_description" + "\n" + d.datalink_name  );
        } 
    }   
}
```

Comment: Did you add Jpcap in your classpath?

Comment: No, how i can this ?

Comment: You need to download and install [Jpcap](http://jpcap.gitspot.com/index.html) and then add it to your classpath

Comment: I have installed jpcap and eclipse not found any sytax error nut logcat of adroid sdk tool display me:  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jpcap.JpcapCaptor